# React Native loading screen between pages

Tags: react-native

Can anyone tell me how it is possible to insert a loading screen while a screen is loading. (i am using the React Native Stack Navigator).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. We have a couple of npm libraries to do the task. One is [React native loading spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay) (This package has been currently deprecated). You can read the documents to see how to implement those. If you want to create beautiful animations, You can use [react-native-animated-loader](https://github.com/vikrantnegi/react-native-animated-loader). There are tons of libraries you could find on Github and npm. If you want Instagram-like loading(displaying some placeholder stuff before rendering your react-native component), there is [react-native-easy-content-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-easy-content-loader). Please go through the docs for more info.

You can also implement your own loading screen from scratch and use the  useEffect hook to render the loading screen before the component is loaded